# How to use jQuery with browserify?

Tags: jquery, browserify

I have installed jQuery (v1.11.1) with npm. (I need 1.x since I want to use it with Angular that does not support 2.x).

I am then trying to import the jQuery object with require via browserify, but it seems like the returned object is not the expected so I can't use it.

`var jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery')(window);`

When trying to use it I get `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use jQuery with browserify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has `main` set to `dist/jquery.js`, thus you can simply do this:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');

jQuery('body').text('hello world');
```

Note that jQuery exports its factory only if there is no global `document` property. When used with Browserify, there is one, so what gets exported is not the factory function, but the regular jQuery object.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I can't believe it would be that simple. I wonder if this is new with 1.11. This site advised me to use require('jquery/dist/jquery')(window) on jQuery version before v2.1.0. So, apparently this is not longer correct.  http://learnjs.io/blog/2013/11/23/backbone-jquery-browserify/